# JavaScript issue with form values

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have updated values when i click the button, but it doesn't work. I'm getting only empty array.

```
var title = form.title.value;
var data = form.date.value;
var priority = form.priority.value;
var description = form.textarea.value;
var check = form.check.value;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];
    obj.title = title;
    obj.date = data;
    obj.priority = priority;
    obj.description = description;
    obj.check = check;
    arr.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem('todo_list', JSON.stringify(arr));
    var tasks = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('todo_list') );
    console.log(tasks);
});
```

Comment: The `var`s set outside the click handler are set immediately, and not updated, so no matter what's on the form when the button is clicked, the values used are probably blank from when the JS first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching all the form values when your code first runs, presumably when the page is loaded. Shouldn't you be fetching them after the button is clicked? Remove all five of the `var` statements at the top, and fetch the form values directly inside the `click` event listener:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];
    obj.title = form.title.value;
    obj.date = form.date.value;
    obj.priority = form.priority.value;
    obj.description = form.textarea.value;
    obj.check = form.check.value;
    arr.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem('todo_list', JSON.stringify(arr));
    var tasks = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('todo_list') );
    console.log(tasks);
});
```

You can also clean up the code a bit by setting all the values inside the object/array literals. Depending on what you need, this can be a nicer way to do it:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var arr = [
        {
            title: form.title.value,
            date: form.date.value,
            priority: form.priority.value,
            description: form.textarea.value,
            check: form.check.value
        }
    ];
    localStorage.setItem('todo_list', JSON.stringify(arr));
    var tasks = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('todo_list') );
    console.log(tasks);
});
```